# Bootstrap3 . Can I Embed a fixed region within a responsive site?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 in responsive mode. Is it possible to embed a region or regions on the site to be **fixed** rather then **responsive**. A fixed width table, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! Just don't use class="table" attribute on table definition.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <table width="200">
        <tr>
          <td>cell1</td>
          <td>cell2</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>cell3</td>
          <td>cell4</td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">sidebar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16851/